# "Play on" UPNP/DLNA device from OSX

Tags: audio, network, mediaplayer

I have a TV and an AV-receiver which are DLNA-capable and which are attached to my home network together with a Windows 7 desktop and a MBP running OSX Lion. I can access audio from both computers using a DLNA-server software on either computer (built in DLNA-server on Windows, PS3Media Server on OSX). So far this setup works fine and i can browse through my audio on the receiver.

However the TV and the receiver also act as UPNP/DLNA media renderer. For example I can use my phone to display photos on the TV (e.g. using the Twonky app on Android). On Windows, I can use Windows Media Player to play audio on either device without having to touch any remote control. I select the track/playlist I want to listen to, right click select "Play on" (maybe not the exact wording as my Windows is German) and select one of the two devices (e.g. the AVR for audio). Now I'm looking for the same for OSX. Either an application/media player which can use a media renderer as output device or an app which redirects all audio output to such a device. Does anybody know such software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to find UPnP Controller for Mac.

For example http://oss.linn.co.uk/trac/wiki/Kinsky is one of freeware. You can drag files to your UPnP device to play. Create playlist. Start streaming from UPnP server serources etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I could only find one mention of UPnP/DLNA on that page, and the app that it linked to is exclusively audio. Do you have an example that supports video as well?

Answer (score 1):

The closest I have found is www.skifta.com - you can use your Android phone to start videos from your Mac/PC to be displayed in your UPnP device. Which is almost OK for my needs. You just need to install thing in your Mac and Application in your phone. So phone acts like remote control between your computer and Media center.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SofaPlay](https://itunes.apple.com/app/sofaplay/id566429668?mt=12).  There is a free version to see if it will work for you.  The paid version allows unlimited video streaming instead of 2min for the free version.

Answer (score 0):

It might be late but I guess AirFoil for Mac does what you want: http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/

It basically asks you to select the software from which you want to redirect the output, and the device on which you to connect.

Hope it helps.

Comment: seems to do airplay only, not DLNA/upnp

Comment: @hbogert yes it does DLNA, that's how it helped me: on my mac I could only use Airplay before, with it I could broadcast.
I even had exchanges with the developer later because it didn't work with Sitecom WMA-1000 which is supposed to handle both Airplay and DLNA (and their DLNA support is crappy).

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieved with **VLC**.
Use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to install it:

```
brew cask install vlc
```

then go to `File` -> `Convert / Stream...` (or press cmd+shift+S) to open the Streaming window. Then select you file and click `Stream` button.

[image]

later clicking the `Setup Streaming...` button, select `UDP` as the streaming type and add the IP address where your DLNA device is running. Most of the time, it should be running in port 1900, otherwise check your server settings.

[image]

Finally clicking `Apply`, then `Stream` will stream the file to your device.

Also (UPnP related answer, but not exactly with DLNA protocol), you could stream with VLC to devices using the [Google Cast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cast) protocol (like a Chromecast). When you open a video, go to `Playback`->`Renderer`->`Your device`

[image]

**Google Chrome** has some streaming capabilities as well. Go to Settings button (`⋮`) -> `Cast...`

[image]

then you could choose if you want to share your browser's tab or your entire screen's desktop.

[image]

Comment: Didn't work — VLC doesn't find any devices that other software does. -1 for demonstrating using Chromecast on a DLNA question.

Comment: @Andreas my bad, I thought Chromecast worked with DLNA, but now I've realised it uses a propietary protocol. Anyway, I've updated the answer to show how to stream with VLC and DLNA

Comment: I was unable to make it work using files that have successfully been streamed by Windows 10 using the same hardware. VLC might be streaming, but there's no reaction from the renderer (Kodi 18). The port number is not configurable in Kodi so I assumed the standard.